# 3d Holographic Fan

Tags: image

Good afternoon everyone.  Quick question, I am trying to create a really simple 3d image of an existing logo for a friend's restaurant and then take said image to upload onto his 3d Fan.  I am a complete novice at this so hoping someone can tell me if Blender is the right path for this as it appears to be very robust (and free) but again, I'm a 3d novice so maybe its overkill?

Comment: Maybe ask a friend who already knows the software, unless you want to learn 3d

Comment: Blender is definitely capable of doing it. Learning the software is admittedly a steep curve, so it may be hard to justify the investment just for this one case. However if you plan on using it further afterwards for other purposes or doing it just for fun, then go right ahead